# p:fileUpload not showing any thing upon clicking on it

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{editBean.relatedFileEditUpload}"
                        style="width:370px;"
                        rendered="#{editBean.uploadFileRender}"
                        process="relatedFileUploadingEditForm:relatedFileType"
                        update="relatedFileUploadingEditForm:messages relatedFileUploadingEditForm:relatedFileType">
</p:fileUpload>
```

The above is the code snippet that I am using. But it is not showing the browse option up on clicking the upload button.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `mode` and `value` attributes. So try let's say `mode="simple"` and `value="#{editBean.yourFile}"` (org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile)